# Issue chaining Completable after flatMapCompletable

Tags: kotlin, rx-java2

For each, `Event`, I want need to send it and validate it. I have this code:

```
fun process(): Completable = 
    eventsDao.findAll()
        .flatMapCompletable(this::sendEventToServer)
        .andThen(this::validate) //Error here

fun send(event: Event): Completable = 
    //code 

fun validate(event: Event): Completable =
    //code
```

> Error:(14, 18) None of the following functions can be called with the
>   arguments supplied: @CheckReturnValue @SchedulerSupport public final
>   fun andThen(p0: ((CompletableObserver) -> Unit)!): Completable!
>   defined in io.reactivex.Completable
>
> @CheckReturnValue @SchedulerSupport public final fun 
>   andThen(p0: ((MaybeObserver) -> Unit)!):
>   Maybe<(???..???)>! defined in io.reactivex.Completable
>
> @CheckReturnValue @SchedulerSupport public final fun 
>   andThen(p0: ((Observer) -> Unit)!):
>   Observable<(???..???)>! defined in io.reactivex.Completable
>
> and so on

Problem is that here:

```
.andThen(this::validate)
```

I don't have the `event` itself. How can I chain these `Completable`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer:

```
fun process(): Completable = 
    eventsDao.findAll()
        .flatMapCompletable(this::processEvent)

fun processEvent(event: Event) =
    send(event).concatWith(validate(event))
```

I will really appreciate any advice or a better manner to do it